# Automticaly setup add-on Heroku-Postgresql with one command

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I want use PostgreSQL 9 in my app and to host on Heroku. By default heroku use Postgres 8.3.
To use Postgres 9, I need to install add-on heroku-postgres(https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql). In the documentation I found several steps to use Postgresql 9. It is simple, but I need to automatize and simplify all deploy steps.

Questions, I need at least one answer from these questions:

- Is it possible by default use Postgresql 9 in Heroku without any add-on?
- Is it possible to setup custom database urls names when I add the add-on like `heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev CUSTOME_HEROKU_DATABASE_URL_NAME`?
- Is it possible to use last database url in promote, e.g. `heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_LAST`?
- Is it possible to promote database on adding add-on e.g.:`heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev --promote`?

I don't want to use tools like `grep` or `sed`. This solution I built already.

Answer (score 1):

- PostgreSQL 9 is the default on Heroku now.
- When you create a new Heroku database, it will *always* auto-generate a name for you (a color), you cannot change this.
- There is no way to promote a new database to default without using grep / sed / customizations.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible by default use Postgresql 9 in Heroku without any add-on?

The `dev` plan *will* be the default on heroku. If you want it to be the default for you now, you can by adding [this feature flag](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-default-heroku-postgresql-dev/):

```
    heroku labs:enable default-heroku-postgresql-dev
```

> Is it possible to setup custom database urls names when I add the add-on like heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev CUSTOME_HEROKU_DATABASE_URL_NAME?

No, not yet.

> Is it possible to use last database url in promote, e.g. heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_LAST?

No, but if you have that flag set up, when you push code for the first time it will provision a `dev` database for you and it will have been promoted.

> Is it possible to promote database on adding add-on e.g.:heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev --promote?

No, but interesting idea.